# Google Data Studio: Compare daily sales to 7-day average

Tags: looker-studio

I have a data source with daily sales per product.
I want to create a field that calculates the average daily sales for the 7 last days, for each product and day (e.g. on day 10 for product A, it will give me the average sales for product A on days 3 - 9; on Day 15 for product B, I'll see the average sales of B on days 8 - 14).
Is this possible?

Example data (I have the first 3 columns. need to generate the *fourth*)
Date    Product Sales   *7-Day Average*
1/11    A   983 201
2/11    A   650 983
3/11    A   328 817
4/11    A   728 654
5/11    A   246 672
6/11    A   613 587
7/11    A   575 591
8/11    A   601 589
9/11    A   462 534
10/11   A   979 508
11/11   A   148 601
12/11   A   238 518
13/11   A   53  517
14/11   A   500 437
15/11   A   684 426
16/11   A   261 438
17/11   A   69  409
18/11   A   159 279
19/11   A   964 281
20/11   A   429 384
21/11   A   731 438
1/11    B   790 471
2/11    B   265 486
3/11    B   94  487
4/11    B   66  490
5/11    B   124 477
6/11    B   555 357
7/11    B   190 375
8/11    B   232 298
9/11    B   747 218
10/11   B   557 287
11/11   B   432 353
12/11   B   526 405
13/11   B   690 463
14/11   B   350 482
15/11   B   512 505
16/11   B   273 545
17/11   B   679 477
18/11   B   164 495
19/11   B   799 456
20/11   B   749 495
21/11   B   391 504

Haven't really tried anything. Couldn't figure out how to do get started with this)

Answer (score 0):

**This may not be the super perfect solution** but it does give your expected result in a crude way.

- Cross-join the same data source first as shown in the screenshot
- Use the calculated field to get the last 7 day average

`(CASE WHEN Date (Table 2) BETWEEN DATETIME_SUB(Date (Table 1), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DATETIME_SUB(Date (Table 1), INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN  Sales (Table 2) ELSE 0 END)/7`

-

[image]